# c# Using static variables in different projects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a solution with two projects which act as Server and Client respectively. The Client is a simple console application which sends data to the server. The server is a WPF application which receives the data and displays it in a datagrid. The MVVM approach is used here.

In the Server UI there are three textboxes in which the user can type in:

**IP Address: ("127.0.0.1")**

**Port:       (some port)**

**Delimeter:  (some char like '@' for example)**

The challenge for me in this one is that, whatever delimeter the user provides, it should be used in the client project, to be put in between the data which is to be sent. For example the client sends:

*Name + Delimeter + Surname + Delimeter + Age*

**What i have tried:**

I added a Utils class with static fields for IPAddress, port and delimeter like this:

```
public class Utils
{
    public static string IP_ADDRESS = " ";
    public static int PORT = 0;
    public static char DELIMETER = '\0';

}
```

I then tried to change these values in my ViewModel where the respective properties which are bound to the UI are by assigning them:

```
private void storeData()
{
    Utils.IP_ADDRESS = IP;
    Utils.PORT = Port;
    Utils.DELIMETER = Delimeter;
}
```

In the client program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client(Utils.IP_ADDRESS, Utils.PORT);

        while (true)
        {
            client.SendData("some Name" + Utils.DELIMETER + "some Surname" +  Utils.DELIMETER + some Age + Utils.DELIMETER + "something else");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that whenever i start a new Client instance the values from the util class are still the default ones (null).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the _client_ be specifying the connection information to establish a connection?  In any case static vars are restricted to an AppDomain so the client process will have its own copies of the static properties (which is why they are null).

Comment: If a server can change its integration specs *while it's running* then the only way for the client to get the updated specs would be to ask the server.  Maybe create a generic operation the client can call where the server returns the delimiter (and any other specs the client might need)?

Comment: You should use a configuration file and read/write the shared variables (IP_ADDRESS, PORT, DELIMITER) from/into this file.

Comment: @DStanley So what can you suggest me to do in this case for the client to have the same information which the user enters in the textboxes: Sorry but im new to all this.

Comment: You could use the same form on the client that you're using on the server, or read the connection info from a config file.

Comment: @David The server cannot change the specs while running. When i create an instance of the server i provide  ip and port as parameters.

Comment: @IndritBulica: Why are the values being set in the UI then?  Why does the delimiter change from a global known value at all?

Comment: @DamianGalletini how can i do this? Config file in a separate class or separate project?

Comment: No need for a config file. When a client connects to the server, there should be a short negotiation: the server sends the delimiter on client connect (just a writeline of the delimiter), the client would read and store the delimiter after a connection (just a readline after the connection).

Comment: @David The values are set in the UI just to demonstrate that the server can be created with different port values and different delimeters, and the clients should connect every time to this port provided, and send the data using that delimeter specified.

Comment: @IndritBulica you can create a XML file on a shared location and read/write from there.

Comment: @AdamSills if the client don't know the server IP address and port there is no way to make any negotiation.

Comment: IP Addresses and Ports are details that are needed for the client to communicate to the server. You want the client to get this information from the server before communicating? That's impossible. You will need to send this information to the clients some way, and whatever way you used to send that information is more robust than your client/server communication, so that means you're effectively short-circuiting yourself.

Comment: Just as explanation, the server starts first. The user then provides the information on the textboxes and clicks connect and waits for clients to connect.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR that is not a problem because i can just Loopback the Ip Address and hardcode the port. I am trying to figure out the part that the client needs to use the delimeter specified in the server UI.

Comment: But if you hardcode the port then your UI is useless. If your problem is only the delimiter then you need 2 different service calls: One that the client can make to query the proper delimiter and then whatever else you need the client to do. The query that gets the delimiter must not depend on the delimiter. And if you Loopback then it's not really a client server architecture

Comment: @IndritBulica: Let's take a step back... What is the intended functionality of this system?  It sounds like you've taken a wrong design step and that's confusing the rest of us.

Comment: If the user provides the information to the server, there is no way for the clients to know this information. It might work on a single machine, but that's not the point of IP addresses and ports, so you're using that wrong. Connection information must be provided to the clients, not the server.

Comment: @David The client is a simple console application which sends data to the server in the form : Name@Surname@Age (@ represents the delimeter). The server is a WPF application with the three textboxes which i specified above. A button should start the server. Once the server is started, it waits for clients to connect which can send their data that the server displays in a datagrid in another view. The textbox values have the information which the clients should use to connect to the server.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR this is intended to be a simple application which uses localhost using tcp connection. When i said i can loopback the ip address and hardcode the port, it was just to have the application throw no errors, and if i find a way to pass the delimeter i assume can use the same logic to pass the ip address and port.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your problem:

1. The server can change ip or ports at will and the clients will somehow guess the new port and connect.
2. The server changes the delimiter at will and the clients adapt to the new delimiter.

Problem 1 is impossible. Information cannot magically get transferred to clients before the client connects to the server, and the client needs ip and ports to connect to the server. Whatever technique you use to transfer the ip and port to the client is a better communication channel than your client/server, so you don't need a client/server.

Problem 2 [has been solved by WCF already](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx). Use WCF and SOAP or REST (which is just HTML).

Here is a sample of what the code would look like for the clients to determine the delimiter before sending the main request:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener _listener = new TcpListener(12312);            
    public void Start()
    {
        _listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            var request = getRequest(stream);
            if (request == "GetDelimiter")
            {
                SendResponse(Utils.DELIMITER, stream);
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessNameSurnameAge(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Client
{
    private TcpClient _client = new TcpClient();
    public void DoTheThing()
    {
        _client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 12312);
        var stream = _client.GetStream();
        SendRequest("GetDelimiter", stream);
        var delimiter = GetResponse(stream);
        var newRequest = "some Name" + delimiter + "some Surname" + delimiter + "some Age" + delimiter + "something else";
        SendRequest(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Note that I skip over the encoding details of sending data over TCP because it seems like you've already got a handle on that.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer and effort. 
Second it is not inteded to change the values of ip address, port and delimeter continuously as the application is running. Once the values are set they don't need to change. Lastly, i have never used WCF before, and i am looking for a solution only using WPF.

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn WCF as that is .Net's solution to your problem. You are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: As for ip and port, the server cannot communicate that information to clients before the clients connect. That is not possible using TCP.

Comment: Would it not be possible to store the values for ip and port into some variables, and then use those variables in the class where i declare the client(which is in another project), as parameters to the client constructor?

Client client = new Client(string ip, int port)

Comment: No that's not possible. Your client and server are 2 different processes, and processes cannot share their variables. This is the reason for TCP to exist in the first place. WCF is Microsoft's solution to precisely the problem you are facing. Note that projects and processes are 2 different things, but in your case each project ends up being a single process.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in a rather simple manner. Steps i used to solve are as follow:

**In the server:**

1. Created a text file in my solution.
2. When the server starts in my view model, i saved the properties ip, port and delimeter in a string array.
3. Next i used the IO File class to write the content of the array in the text file.

**In the client:**

1. First i read from the file.
2. Next i created the client instance and passed the ip and port as parameters to it's constructor.

Thank you D Stanley and Damian Galletini for your suggestions. Also thank you everybody else who tried to help.

Comment: You are using the filesystem as your communication channel. The file system is much better than your client server, so you don't need a client server.

Comment: Agreed, but the assignment specifies that tcp communication between a server and many clients should be implemented.

Comment: I understand much better now. StackOverflow is dedicated to solve real problems. It is the [site's policy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to explicitely state when the question is about homework, as that usually involves arbitrary constraints, such as yours.